# iOS 7 iAd interstitial ads can not be closed by user

Tags: ios7, iad, interstitial

when i display interstitial ads with

`[interstitial presentFromViewController:self];`

i get the warning that this method is deprecated in iOS 7. But it still works fine!

When i display the ad view with

```
[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
[interstitial presentInView:self.view];
```

i get no warning and the ad is loading but there is no (X) in the ad that the user can close the ad.

Do somebody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? Also when the ad is tapped, I get a black screen instead of the view I presented the ad in.

Answer (score 1):

hey there this is the troublemaker 
[interstitial presentInView:self.view]; 
instead try this (delegate methods) t'should be removed manualy

```
-(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd{
    if (interstitial  != nil){
    _adPlaceholderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:_adPlaceholderView];
    [interstitial presentInView:_adPlaceholderView];
    }
   and on did unload
- (void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{

    NSLog(@"ad has been unloaded");
    [_adPlaceholderView removeFromSuperview];
    _adPlaceholderView = nil;


}
```

I have the same bug Use the old API or put custom x button .I thinks this is a bug from presentinView . i am not sure it could be apple desired feature there's no documentation on this.At least i haven't seen any.Please share if you find something official  on this.